# Route without lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, nancy

Below is [the official example](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes) for registering routes in [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy). But what if I do not want to "do something" in that method, but do it in `DoSomething()`, instead?

```
public class ProductsModule : NancyModule
{
    public ProductsModule()
    {
        Get["/products/{id}"] = _ =>
        {
            //do something
        };
    }
}

public abstract class NancyModule : INancyModule, IHideObjectMembers
{
    public RouteBuilder Get { get; }
}

public class RouteBuilder : IHideObjectMembers
{
    public RouteBuilder(string method, NancyModule parentModule);
    public Func<dynamic, dynamic> this[string path] { set; }
}
```

I do not know what signature  `DoSomething` should have. Can this work something like below? It is not that I must not use lambda expression; I am just curious because all these patterns Nancy is using look quite bizarre and unique.

```
public class ProductsModule : NancyModule
{
    ???? DoSomething(????)
    {
        //do something
        return ????
    }

    public ProductsModule()
    {
        Get["/products/{id}"] = DoSomething;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call you method inside the lambda ?

Comment: Yes, that was the first workaround I came up with. But is it possible to call the method without using lambda expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Nancy documentation:

> A route Action is the behavior which is invoked when a request is matched to a route. It is **represented by a lambda expression of type `Func<dynamic, dynamic>`** where the dynamic input is a `DynamicDictionary`, a special dynamic type that is defined in Nancy and is covered in Taking a look at the `DynamicDictionary`.

So, you can simply do the following:

```
Get["/products/{id}"] = DoSomething;
```

Where `DoSomething` is defined as:

```
private dynamic DoSomething(dynamic parameters)
```